# Create dict from array or list OR just parse the list for X and Y coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, parsing

I have 3000 lines of data like this:

```
['OFFD.271818,271818,"LINESTRING (16.303895355263016 48.18772778239529, 16.304571765172827 48.18758202488568, 16.30482300975865 48.18755484403183, 16.305031079294384 48.187546649202545, 16.30536730486924 48.187533407177206, 16.307523452290432 48.18753396398144, 16.309072536732444 48.18748514596115, 16.312777938045286 48.18734458451529, 16.313426882251083 48.18727411748434, 16.315405366265555 48.186920966444205, 16.316609208646593 48.18670268519608, 16.317260447683868 48.18652861710351, 16.31853471535412 48.186166775088815)",U4,4,U-Bahn,']
```

I want using matplotlib to create a plot, but I need X and Y coordinates.
The Targe is: U4 (from the line)
Coordinates are:

```
16.303895355263016 48.18772778239529, 16.304571765172827 48.18758202488568, 16.30482300975865 48.18755484403183, 16.305031079294384 48.187546649202545, 16.30536730486924 48.187533407177206, 16.307523452290432 48.18753396398144, 16.309072536732444 48.18748514596115, 16.312777938045286 48.18734458451529, 16.313426882251083 48.18727411748434, 16.315405366265555 48.186920966444205, 16.316609208646593 48.18670268519608, 16.317260447683868 48.18652861710351, 16.31853471535412 48.186166775088815
```

I do not get how to parse this string with numpy and create the dataset:
U4: coordinates for X: ... and for Y:....

Any hints?